# Implementing binary semaphore for threads using signals in c

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, signals, semaphore

The following is what I tried:

```
int status;

sigset_t waitset;

void sem_init(int status) {
    status = status;
    sigemptyset(waitset);
    sigaddset(waitset, SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, waitset, NULL);
}

void sem_down() {
    if (status == 0) {
        int sig;
        
        while(sig != SIGUSR1) // SIGUSR1 macro cannot be 0
            sigwait(waitset, sig);
    }
    status = 0;
}

void sem_up() {
    status = 1;
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
}
```

To be honest I didn't quite understand how **sigwait** and **sigprocmask** work.
The exercise says that for simplicity there is no need to block each thread alone, so I can block the entire process.

The function signatures must be like I wrote (so there can be global variables).

**What do I need to change to make it work?**

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question.

Comment: There are far, far better and easier to use options than signals available for threads to communicate with each other. Why reinvent the wheel anyways; posix has semaphores already.

Comment: This is the exercise we were given. There is nothing I can do with it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], the expected output and the output you are getting instead.

Comment: You cannot implement a *bona fide* semaphore on top of signals alone.  Semaphores have memory-ordering semantics that signal handlers and synchronous signal-handling mechanisms cannot provide.

Comment: You *can* implement semaphore-like mechanisms for execution ordering, however, which I guess is what you're expected to do.

Comment: "*I didn't quite understand how **sigwait** and **sigprocmask** work.*" -- that's fine, no one is born knowing these things.  You have to learn sometime.  But (i) that's undoubtedly part of the purpose of the exercise, and (ii) your first recourse should be to these functions' **documentation**, such as [`sigwait()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) and [`sigprocmask`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html).

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  A signal-based design like this has some fundamental problems.  Semaphores in general have a value/count, so that two of your `sem_up()` calls in a row should allow two of your `sem_down()` calls to work without blocking, but two `SIGUSR1` signals in a row will likely be coalesced into a single signal when delivered.  You could increment `status` with each `sem_up()` call, but that will make race conditions much more likely.  `status++;` is NOT atomic.

Comment: Are you allowed to [`#include <stdatomic.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)? What you're trying to do _cannot_ be done without using "atomic" operations. Here's why: Suppose `status==1`, and two threads concurrently call `sem_down()`. Both threads could test `status`, both could see `status==1`, and both would then set `status=0`. Neither thread would wait. That's not what you want. Your teacher already should have explained how to use the functions in stdatomic.h if they expect you to succeed in this assignment.

Comment: Re "*What do I need to change to make it work?*", In what way does it not work? Your code isn't complete, much less demonstrate your problem. Please provide runnable code, the behaviour you get, and the behaviour you desire.

Comment: Surely your compiler is hitting you with at least 6-7 significant warnings and errors in the presented code alone, many of them about mismatched argument types.  How about you start by fixing those? At this point in the curriculum, you should have some idea about what they mean and how to address them.